# How to use input() function of Python in bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to integrate a Python script into a bash script. However when I use the `input()` function, I am getting an `EOFError`. How can I fix this problem?

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 <<END
print(input(">>> "))
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot source both the script and the user input through the program's standard input. (That's in effect what you're trying to do. `<<` redirects the standard input.)

Ideally, you would provide the script as command line argument instead of stdin using `-c SCRIPT` instead of `<<EOF heredoc EOF`:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 -c 'print(input(">>> "))'
```

Note that you may need to mind your quoting and escaping in case you have a more complicated Python script with nested quotes.

You can still let the script run over multiple lines, if you need to:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 -c '
import os.path

path_name = input("enter a path name >>> ")

file_exists = os.path.exists(path_name)

print("file " + path_name + " " + 
      ("exists" if file_exists else "does not exist"))
'
```

Note that you will get into trouble when you want to use single quotes in your Python script, as happens when you want to print `doesn't` instead of `does not`.

You can work around that using several approaches. The one I consider most flexible (apart from putting you into quoting hell) is surrounding the Python script with double quotes instead and properly escape all inner double quotes and other characters that the shell interprets:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 -c "
print(\"It doesn't slice your bread.\")
print('But it can', 'unsliced'[2:7], 'your strings.')
print(\"It's only about \$0. Neat, right?\")
"
```

Note that I also escaped `$`, as the shell would otherwise interpret it inside the surrounding double quotes and the result may not be what you wanted.

Comment: blubberdiblub, How can I get the input value and assign it to a variable? For example: ```#!/bin/bash
python3 -c 'print(input(">>>"))'
python3 <<END
value_of_input = ?
END```

Comment: Do you need the input just within your Python script or do you need it to "leak out" into the surrounding bash script?

Comment: I need to give a path name to the python script. In order to get the path name, I decided to use `input()` function. However it gave an `EOFError`. I need to run a bash script and this bash script contains Python codes. Many Python codes can be written in that bash script but `input` function can not be used properly. That's my problem. I guess you understood what I was trying to show you in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I understand. And the reason it comes back with an `EOFError` is that you're using a here document. I.e. the `<<`. This puts the script into `python3`'s standard input instead of the terminal's standard input. So `python3` just receives the script. Then starts interpreting the script and then when it hits `input()` there's no more there, as from Python's point of view, the input ended right after the script. After the here document. Hence you should be using `-c '...'` instead of `<<EOF ... EOF`

Comment: I edited the second example to show that reading and using input works.

Comment: Thank you, `python3 -c '...'` seems more practical than what I was trying to do.